# cond_broadcast and scheduling order

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

I am writing a producer/consumers program. I have 3 consumers reading from a queue and one producer writing in the queue.
When the producer write something in the queue it broadcasts it using phtread_cond_broadcast. Then the consumers wake up but I have find a pattern in my programm. One of the consummer is always wake up before the others and then clear the queue. My question is it is normal that the broadcast wake up all the threads in the same order every time ?

Producer :

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
if(/* write something */)
phtread_cond_broadcast(&cond1)
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
```

Consumer :

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
while(/* queue vide */)
phtread_cond_wait(&cond1);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
```

Comment: Your pthread_cond_wait should probably have a condition parameter...

Answer (score 0):

If only one consumer can possibly have work to do when the producer writes something, you should consider using `pthread_cond_signal()` instead.  That way you'll wake up just one (n.b. according to the documentation it could be more than one), instead of all the consumers.  Waking up all of them results in the "thundering herd" phenomenon, where everybody rushes to grab the same work item, and then most of them go back to sleep having done nothing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page `If more than one thread is blocked on a condition  variable,
     the  scheduling policy determines the order in which threads
     are unblocked.`

So it sounds like if a bunch of factors (scheduling policy, library version, etc) are the same the order would be the same as well.